# PHP converting utf-16 to ascii

Tags: php, emoji

I'm trying to convert some encoded text to display on a website; the specific example is converting the string "d83edd2a" to the  emoji.

Apparently the encoding is UTF-16 but php detects it as ASCII.

I've tried using hex2bin but this returns "Ø>Ý*" and php detects this as UTF-8, which makes sense to me.

I've tried playing around with a couple of different attempts

```
$newCode = mb_convert_encoding($code, "ASCII", "UTF-16");
```

But this returns "????"

```
$newCode = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($code), 'ASCII', $hex);
```

But this also returns "????"

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I've ended up tying myself up in knots!

Comment: Well, you converted from UTF-16 to ASCII. What did you expect? ASCII's character table is _very_ limited.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to accomplish? Do you want to convert `d83edd2a` to an emoji or vice versa?

Comment: I'm wanting to convert the hex to emoji - d3L's response solved this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to convert the string `d83edd2a` to the corresponding emoji.

The most straightforward way is to simply:

```
echo hex2bin('d83edd2a');
```

However this assumes the client uses UTF-16 charset.

If the client uses a different charset you need to convert it first, otherwise you will just see garbage.

But you cannot just use *any* encoding (like ASCII) because emojis are specific to unicode.

(ASCII simply doesn't "know" the concept of emojis.)

You need to use UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Since you mentioned website you want "UTF-8", it is the de facto standard charset for modern websites.

You can convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 like this:

```
// First convert the string to binary data
// We know this is encoded in UTF-16
$UTF16Str = hex2bin('d83edd2a');
// Then we convert from UTF-16 to something more common like UTF-8
$UTF8Str  = mb_convert_encoding($UTF16Str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');

echo $UTF8Str;
```

As a last step, make sure you communicate the charset to the client (you can do this in HTML or PHP):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- inside <head> -->
```

Or in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```